# Use Bootloader to dual boot into Win 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bootloader

Part 1:

I am planning to install Ubuntu in my computer and I don't like the GRUB boot loader. I want a boot loader that has the following functionality:

1. Allows me to set the default OS(I want to set Win 10 or Ubuntu as default from time to time)
2. Should provide some amount customization (Default timer, ability to rearrange OS , Look customization(maybe))

Is there any boot loader with the aforementioned features? Also a link to how to install it or a documentation would be helpful.

Part 2:

I have already set aside a space for Ubuntu in my PC but I formatted it to NTFS(Drive 'H'). Should I leave the space unallocated or will be able to install Ubuntu without any problems in NTFS ?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146784/is-grub-the-best-bootloading-solution-is-there-an-easier-alternative) regarding GRUB alternatives. I don't think you can install Ubuntu on an NTFS partition, the Ubuntu installer can correctly format it for you. I would recommend unallocating the space before you start the install to make sure Windows doesn't get mad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Part 1:

Use the inbuilt GRUB2 bootloader. It is more than sufficient. Also there is a GRUB-CUSTOMIZER project that you can find on the net that allows to completely customise GRUB.

Part 2:

Do not begin installation of ubuntu with a NTFS partition. Linux does not recoganise that partition. format it to unallocated or even better get a third party allocator like AOMEI partition to allocate the space into ext3 or ext4 (These are the preferred disk formats to install ubuntu).